# Getting codec registry error "Codec not found for requested operation: [map<varchar, double> <-> java.util.Map]" when not using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, datastax

I am trying to get data directly from the Cassandra and store it using model class but failing to do so. I am able to do it by object mapper which I am not trying to use to keep the number of lines less as possible. I tried many stack answers but none of them worked. I am still new to Cassandra and not sure if this could be achieved. Please go easy on me, Thanks!

**This is my model class**

```
@Table("ticket_data")
public class TicketData {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name="user_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String customerId;

    @Column("tickets")
    private Set<Map<String, Double>> tickets;

}
```

**My repositoryClass**

```
@Repository
public interface TicketDataRepository extends CrudRepository<TicketData, String> {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ticket_data WHERE customerId=?0 LIMIT 1")
    TicketData findByCustomerId(String customerId);
}
```

**Table Schema**

```
create table ticket_data
(
    customerId            text primary key,
    tickets               set<frozen<map<text, double>>>
)
```

**Error that I am getting:**

```
Codec not found for requested operation: [map<varchar, double> <-> java.util.Map]; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [map<varchar, double> <-> java.util.Map]
```